# Best practices for float multiplication in C++ or C?

Tags: c, precision, multiplication, floating-accuracy

I need to perform a simple multiplication of 400 * 256.3. The result is 102520. Straight forward and simple. But to implement this multiplication in C++ (or C) is a little tricky and confusing to me.

I understand floating point number is not represented as it is in computer. I wrote the code to illustrate the situation. Output is attached too.

So, if I do the multiplication using float type variable, I am subjected to rounding error. Using double type variable would have avoided the problem. But let's say I have a very limited resource on the embedded system and I have to optimize the variable type to the very best I could, how can I perform the multiplication using float type variable and not susceptible to rounding error?

I knew the floating point math done by computer is not broken at all. But I am curious for best practice to perform floating point math. 256.3 is just a value for illustration. I would not know what floating point value I will get during runtime. But it is for sure, a floating point value.

```
int main()
{
    //perform 400 * 256.3
    //result should be 102520

    float floatResult = 0.00f;
    int intResult = 0;
    double doubleResult = 0.00;

    //float = int * float
    floatResult = 400 * 256.3f;
    printf("400 * 256.3f = (float)->%f\n", floatResult);

    //float = float * float
    floatResult = 400.00f * 256.3f;
    printf("400.00f * 256.3f = (float)->%f\n", floatResult);

    printf("\n");

    //int = int * float
    intResult = 400 * 256.3f;
    printf("400 * 256.3f = (int)->%d\n", intResult);

    //int = float * float;
    intResult = 400.00f * 256.3f;
    printf("400.00f * 256.3f = (int)->%d\n", intResult);

    printf("\n");

    //double = double * double
    doubleResult = 400.00 * 256.3;
    printf("400.00 * 256.3 = (double)->%f\n", doubleResult);

    //int = double * double;
    intResult = 400.00 * 256.3;
    printf("400.00 * 256.3 = (int)->%d\n", intResult);

    printf("\n");

    //double = int * double
    doubleResult = 400 * 256.3;
    printf("400 * 256.3 = (double)->%f\n", doubleResult);

    //int = int * double
    intResult = 400 * 256.3;
    printf("400 * 256.3 = (int)->%d\n", intResult);

    printf("\n");

    //will double give me rounding error?
    if (((400.00 * 256.3) - 102520) != 0) {
        printf("Double give me rounding error!\n");
    }

    //will float give me rounding error?
    if (((400.00f * 256.3f) - 102520) != 0) {
        printf("Float give me rounding error!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Output from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py58I.jpg)

Comment: The answer is simple: You can't. The rounding problem is "built in" on computers using the IEEE floating point format, which is just about all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The value 256.3f is also lying to you and you cannot avoid that.

Comment: You can use an alternate data type e.g. a fixed-precision type or a rational/fractions library.

Comment: @Olaf I mean to say C++ or C. The slash is a symbol for "or". I know floating point implementation in computer and I know it is not broken. I am just curious if there is a way for me to use float variable type and not exposed to rounding error.

Comment: @2501 yeah, I understand that. If I could not avoid it, is there any best practice for working with floating point number that you will certainly recommend?

Comment: @LJSeng Nothing specific. Follow best practices.

Comment: You might **know** what the decimal input/output means, but you apparently don't understand them. Otherwise you had not asked. Your question is definitively a dup. What you might notice if you you had read the linked question and the answer(s).If that is an MCU, you should avoid floating point at all.

Comment: avoid `float` unless you know you really need it. Use double instead

Comment: Always amazing to see how programmers can be terrorized by floating-point truncation and "inexact" arithmetic, while not caring at all about the exactness of their input data. Why worry if 256.3 only has four exact digits, while a single-precision float supports 8 of them ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a fixed number of decimal digits (1 in the case of `256.3`) as well as a bounded range of the results, you can use integer multiplication, and adjust for the shift in decimal digits through integer division:

```
int result = (400 * 2563) / 10;
```

Rounding errors are inherent to floating point arithmetics, except for a few cases where all operands can be represented exactly. Whether you choose `float` or `double` just influences *when* the error occurs, not *if*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! But what if I do not know the operand values until runtime?

Comment: What do you know about the float inputs? What is their [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)? Why are rounding errors a problem?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, understand that type `double` has all the same problems as type `float`.  Neither type has infinite precision, so both types are susceptible to precision loss and other problems.

As to what you can do: there are many different problems that come up, depending on what you're doing, and many techniques to overcome them.  Many, many words have been written on these techniques; I suggest doing a web search on "avoiding floating point error".  But the basic points are:

- Know that floating-point results are never exact
- Don't try to compare floating-point numbers for exact equality
- When comparing floating-point numbers for equality, use an appropriate "epsilon" range
- After calculation, it is often appropriate to explicitly round the final value to the desired precision (especially when printing it out)
- Beware of algorithms which cause the precision loss to increase with each step

See also https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/handouts/sciprog.html .

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I appreciate! :)

Answer (score 1):

A key weakness to displaying the problem is the conversion to `int intResult`.  The posted problem is about *multiplying* and *comparing*, but code only shows issues surrounding `int` conversion.

If code needs to convert a FP value to the *nearest* whole number, uses `rint()`, `round()`, `nearbyint()` or  `lround()`, not integer assignment.